# How to filter a time series in Matlab given a time series representation of the filter window?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Assume you have a time series

```
y(n)
```

and a window

```
w(n)=bartlett(L)
```

(or any other window). How can you filter the time series with the window in Matlab? If you apply

```
conv(w,y),
```

you obtain a signal that is longer than y.

Comment: If the problem is simply that the result is longer, use `conv(y,w'same')` or `conv(y,w,'valid')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = filter(w,1,y);
```

Should do the trick. Alternatively, you can use `fftfilt` (which has slightly different syntax).